# JPA for google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine

Hi I am doing one project in JSP with Google application engine. Now I dont want to use Datanucleas JPA. Becuase the queries are quite different from Datanucleus. It really takes time me. so if I can use simple JPA other than Datanuclease will be good. 
Is that possible?

Comment: you can use this for some help https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jpa/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it's not. Google provides a JPA API implementation above its very specific "database" calls the DataStore.

AFAIK, there is no other JPA implementation able to target this datastore. But there are other APIs available: the low-level datastore API, JDO, Objectify, twig-persist, and maybe others I don't know about.

Comment: You can also try Siena (https://github.com/mandubian/siena) which is not specifically designed for GAE and can work for other DB (SQL & NoSQL) and which works perfectly with Play which is the best lightweight web framework for Java...